# discordjs setInterval doesn't update json file

Tags: javascript, json, discord

I want to show online/total members of a discord guild on a website using a bot.

To display the data on the website , I thought I could use jQuery to extract JSON data from a json file, so my friend made a JSON database that is hosted on the website. In the json file the bot should write every 3 seconds the online and total members in the fields `"online" "total"`.

The problem is that the JSON data doesn't update every 3 seconds. I tried consulting discord.js documentation, but it didn't help. Note that I don't know javascript, so it's quite difficult to me to find a solution writing code.

Here's the code of the bot: [index.js code](https://ghostbin.com/paste/pwtsf)
Here's the [config.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4cT0.png) and [db.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7eLg.png)

I think the problem is in the `setInterval`, because db.json should update every 3 seconds and show me the updated results at http://example.com/db.json .

Also, the data inside db.json only updates on bot start.

**Source Code:**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("/config.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
const adapter = new FileSync('db.json')
const db = low(adapter)
const database = require("./db.json")

client.on("ready", () => {
console.log(`
CONNECTED!
[${client.user.tag}]
`)
    let onM = client.guilds.get(config.g).members.filter(member => member.user.presence.status !== "offline").size
    let totM = client.guilds.get(config.g).memberCount


    db.get("members")
        .find({id: "1", online: getOnline(), total: getTotal()})
        .assign({id: "1", online: onM, total: totM})
        .write()

    setInterval(() => {
        db.get("members")
        .find({id: "1", online: getOnline(), total: getTotal()})
        .assign({id: "1", online: onM, total: totM})
        .write()
    }, 3000)
        function getOnline() {
            return database.members.find(z => z.id === "1").online
        };

        function getTotal() {
            return database.members.find(z => z.id === "1").total

        }

    })

client.login(config.token)
```

**config.json**

```
{
    "token":"BotTOKEN",
    "g":"GuildID"
}
```

**db.json**

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "online": 51,
      "total": 216
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my topic.

Comment: Can you please post the code here, (Properly formatted). It's really hard/distracting to try and reproduce your problem looking at images of code.

Comment: Here you go, I added the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because `require('./db.json')` pulls in the json object, assigns it once, and then it never changes. When your code runs, it updates the file once (Changes the online/total amounts), and then your `.find()` no longer works because `database.members.find(z => z.id === "1").total` is finding old data. Why not just write out the json each time:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("/config.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`
    CONNECTED!
    [${client.user.tag}]
    `)

    const updateUsers = () => {
        let onM = client.guilds.get(config.g).members.filter(member => member.user.presence.status !== "offline").size
        let totM = client.guilds.get(config.g).memberCount

        const json = {
            id: "1",
            online: onM,
            total: totM
        };

        const toWrite = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);

        fs.writeFileSync('./db.json', toWrite);
    };

    setInterval(updateUsers, 3000);
    updateUsers();
});

client.login(config.token)
```

Comment: This is the solution. You saved me! Thank you for the effort and for the time spent helping me. You're a legend!